# Django non-ORM models

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I have some REST endpoints on guest server (/users, /companies, /etc). I need to create admin interface for it. I want to use django models with its relationships , but without database including.

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I need to create CRUD interfaces with endpoints, which can helps me to do some my logic staff. For example, i need to update the same time User and Company. With ORM i can do it easily, but without database i can't do it.

I found http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html. Can it helps me to create my wishes? Is there any good examples with providing tastypie with REST?

Comment: A Model is a Database representation, without a DB you shouldn't use models.

Comment: So you want to provide CRUD functionality without a database? Where do you want to save the data then?

Comment: I want to use CRUD interfaces on external API